# KendoUI read() and query() datasource methods inconsistencies

Tags: grid, datasource, kendo-ui

On a button click I  need to read the first page of my data. The common answer is to use the query() method of datasource, specifing page,  and other additional values through the parameterMap. The problem is that in my datasource I am also using aggregates, and the query() methods does not seem to handle them at all. 
Am I right? Is it because only read() uses "transport.read" settings?
Is there another way to reset a grid binded to a datasource to the first page mantaining all datasource settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem (read the first page of data through datasource, with parameters) using "datasource.page(1)" and setting the values in the parameterMap through an "observable" object, so they are updated when I change my parameters and sent through the "page(1)" request.

```
=== JAVASCRIPT ===
var vm = kendo.observable({
    param1: "value1",
    param2: "value2",
    param3: "value3"
});

var datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        parameterMap: function (inputParams, operation) {
            return JSON.stringify($.extend({
                param1: vm.get("param1"),
                param2: vm.get("param2"),
                param3: vm.get("param3"),
            ));
        }
    }
});

$("#btn").bind("click", function(e) {
    // set call parameters, if needed
    vm.set("param1", "new value");
    datasource.page(1);
});


=== HTML ===
<button class="k-button" id="btn">GetData</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep mate there is specific method for paging -> **dataSource.page(3)**. [Here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#page) is link from the documentation.

Comment: Ok, but what if I need to change the parameterMap before I call "page(1)"? Is it possible to programmatically override the parameterMap on each call?

Comment: @Matteo for most of the properties in the kendo web controls, including parameter map for data source you can replace the js property with a function, see doc: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#transportparametermap-function